# Force LangChain agent to use a tool

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

Is there a way to force a LangChain agent to always use a tool?

(my specific use case: I need the agent to look for information in my database as opposed to generally accessible information and my tool searches through my database)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running an agent query, you can explicitly mention about the custom tool.

```
agent(
         "Using Custom Tool please calculate result of 5"
     )
```

Also, in your _run() function, you add custom log for tracking when custom tool is been called.